# Luego de aplicar preventDefault() permanece el efecto

Tags: javascript

buenas tardes, estoy aprendiendo a validar formularios, tengo un problema al momento de realizar el submit.
La cuestion es la siguiente, el programa realiza una verificacion de los campos y me agrega un "ok" o un "error" a un array, luego con un bucle for leo si existe la presencia de un "error" y de ser asi cancelo el envio del formulario con un preventDefault(). El tema es que cuando el usuario corrige lo que esta mal y le vuelve a dar a enviar el preventDefault() sigue teniendo efecto. si yo pongo los valores bien de entrada el formulario se envia correctamente pero si me equivoco una primera vez y se dispara el preventDefault() el usuario ya no tiene manera de realizar el submit.
hay alguna manera de eliminar el preventDefault?

Gracias

```js
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var comentario = document.getElementById("area_comentario");
var boton = document.getElementById("submit");
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
var aviso = document.getElementById("errores_formulario");
var contador_caracteres = document.getElementById("contador_caracteres")
var expReg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
var solo_letras = /[0-9]/
var chequeo = []
var decision_submit = null

boton.addEventListener("click",validar_formulario);

comentario.addEventListener("keyup",contador);

function contador() {
contador_caracteres.innerHTML = "Caracteres restantes: " + (200 - comentario.value.length);
}

function validar_formulario() {

    aviso.innerHTML = "";
    decision_submit = true


    if (nombre.value  === "") {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Introduzca su nombre</p>";
        chequeo[0] = "error";
    } else chequeo[0] = "ok";

    if (nombre.value.length > 30) {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Nombre demasiado largo</p>";
        chequeo[1] = "error";
    } else chequeo[1] = "ok";

    if (solo_letras.test(nombre.value)) {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Su nombre no puede contener numeros</p>";
        chequeo[2] = "error";
    } else chequeo[2] = "ok";

    if (apellido.value === "") {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Introduzca su apellido</p>";
        chequeo[3] = "error";
    } else chequeo[3] = "ok";

    if (apellido.value.length > 30) {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Apellido demasiado largo</p>";
        chequeo[4] = "error";
    } else chequeo[4] = "ok";

    if (solo_letras.test(apellido.value)) {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Su apellido no puede contener numeros</p>";
        chequeo[5] = "error";
    } else chequeo[5] = "ok";

    if (email.value === "") {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Introduzca un email</p>";
        chequeo[6] = "error";
        chequeo[7] = "error";
    } else if (!(email.value === "")) {
        validacion_email();
        chequeo[6] = "ok";
    }

    if (comentario.value === "") {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Realice un comentario o consulta</p>";
        chequeo[8] = "error";
    } else chequeo[8] = "ok";

    if (comentario.value.length > 200) {
        aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Ha excedido los 200 caracteres</p>";
        chequeo[9] = "error";
    } else chequeo[9] = "ok";

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if (chequeo[i]=="error") {
            decision_submit = false;
        }
    }


    if (decision_submit == false) {
        no_enviar();
    }

}

function validacion_email () {
    var validar_correo = expReg.test(email.value)

        if (validar_correo == false) {
            aviso.innerHTML += "<p>* Introduzca un email válido</p>";
            chequeo[7] = "error"
        } else chequeo[7] = "ok"
}

function no_enviar(){
formulario.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
}
```

```css
.contactenos h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(94, 92, 92);  
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.centrado_contacto {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 223, 223);
    color: rgb(94, 92, 92);
}

.ubicacion {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    right: 10%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.ubicacion iframe {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
}

.formulario {
    left: 10%;
}

label {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

input {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
    border: none;
    width: 310px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#contador_caracteres {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    float: right;
}

#errores_formulario {
    color: rgb(238, 9, 9);
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#submit {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5591c5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 300ms ease;
}

#submit:hover {
    color: #5591c5;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.formulario div {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.formulario h4 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="contactenos">
        <p id="contactenos"></p>
        <h3>CONTACTENOS</h3>

        <div class="centrado_contacto">
            <div class="formulario">
                <h4 class="titulo_consulta">REALICE SU CONSULTA</h4>
                <form id="formulario" action="pages/recepcion.html">

                    <div class="nombre">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre">
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="apellido">
                        <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="apellido">
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="email">
                        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email">
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="comentarios">
                        <label for="area_comentario">Comentarios:</label><br>
                        <textarea name="area_comentario" id="area_comentario" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
                        <p id="contador_caracteres">Caracteres restantes: 200</p>
                    </div><br>

                    <div id="errores_formulario"></div>

                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">

                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="ubicacion">

                <h4>DONDE ESTAMOS</h4>
                <div class="iframe_mapa"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d13133.701213699454!2d-58.36770276089819!3d-34.618691112271485!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1649795657587!5m2!1ses!2sar" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe></div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en esta función:

```
function no_enviar(){
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Una vez que agregas ese `eventListener` cada vez que el usuario haga click en `submit` el `event.preventDefault()` se ejecuta automáticamente sin importar si los datos son válidos o no.

En vez de usar el `onClick` del botón, mejor usa el `onSubmit` del `form`.

```
//boton.addEventListener("click",validar_formulario);

formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar_formulario);
```

Y dentro de `validar_folrmulario` en vez de llamar a `no_enviar()` pon `event.preventDefault()` directamente.

Comment: Buen dia Fede, sigue sin funcionar, necesito la manera de reiniciar los parametros iniciales, pero ese preventDefult sigue activado.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno logré solucionarlo, cuando el decisión_submit se define en true or false, hice que se agregue un atributo onsubmit al elemento html, cuyo valor es "return false" si el decision_submit es falso. Y al comienzo de la función validar_formulario() hago que se le asigne un "return true" para resetear el false en caso de haberse equivocado y haber corregido el error.